# PyGObject, Gtk.Entry height has a minimum?

Tags: python, css, gtk, pygobject

[image: Screenshot]

I cannot get the Gtk.Entry's height smaller than in this picture. I have made the text very small and tried setting CSS styles for padding and border. The padding at 10px makes the entry even bigger and at 0px is the same as not adding the padding tag. You can see that the Gtk.Label is using the same size font and it is much smaller. Using PyGObject with Gtk3. Any ideas?

```
.settings_label {
  color: white;
  font-size: 6px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.settings_entry {
  color: white;
  font-size: 6px;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 1px;
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to figure this out. So far, only using `all: unset;` removes the padding from around the top, bottom, and sides. Unfortunately, that also means that the curved border, it's color, and it's behavior when focusing/etc. is also unset, so it's basically just a space with editable text. Theoretically, you could set all those properties yourself, but that would be a lot of work. I'll keep trying, and I'll let you know if I find anything better...

Comment: Please add the code you used to generate the Gtk Grid image.

Comment: @theGtknerd You don't necessarily need the code that produced the `Grid` image. You just need a window with an entry, and code that sets the style to the given CSS. One entry is enough to demonstrate the problem. But yes, the OP should have provided a [example]...